# How to create a vector of functions from an iterator of functions

Tags: rust

I have an iterator of functions (i_adder). I want to get a vector(nv_adder) from this iterator.

```
struct Int{
    i : i32
}


fn main() {

    let adder = move |x : &Int| Int{ i: x.i + 1}; 
    let v_adder=vec![adder];
    let i_adder=v_adder.iter();
    let nv_adder=i_adder.collect::<Vec<&dyn Fn(&Int)->Int>>();
}
```

> error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<&dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r Int) -> Int>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&[closure@src/main.rs:8:17: 8:49]`

[code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=51f808ba3c07d4b119ba804411f782ae)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. But I still don´t know what why collect doesn´t work.

```
struct Int{
    i : i32
}


fn main() {

    let adder = move |x : &Int| Int{ i: x.i + 1}; 
    let v_adder=vec![adder];
    let i_adder=v_adder.iter();
    let v = Vec::from_iter(i_adder);
    let p= v[0](&Int{i:1}).i;
    println!("{}",p)

}
```

[code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7d7e7744be854d8255f6ec256bf2b033)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Box` smart pointer and type specification :

```rust
fn main() {

    let adder = move |x : &Int| Int{ i: x.i + 1}; 
    let v_adder: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&Int) -> Int>>=vec![Box::new(adder)];
    let i_adder=v_adder.iter();
    let nv_adder=i_adder.collect::<Vec<&Box<dyn Fn(&Int) -> Int>>>();
}
```

You need the `Box` smart pointer since the compilator does not know the size of a trait object at compile time.

Comment: Size isn't a problem for `&dyn Fn(&Int) -> Int`. The lifetime is though.