# Why the rust compiler say that fromIterator isn't implement although I can use it

Tags: rust

This is the sequel of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73496797/how-to-create-a-vector-of-functions-from-an-iterator-of-functions/73503540#73503540)

```
struct Int{
    i : i32
}


fn main() {

    let adder = move |x : &Int| Int{ i: x.i + 1}; 
    let v_adder=vec![adder];
    let i_adder=v_adder.iter();
    let nv_adder=i_adder.collect::<Vec<&dyn Fn(&Int)->Int>>();
}
```

I have a long error message with this sentence:

> help: the trait `FromIterator<&[closure@src/main.rs:8:17: 8:49]>` is not implemented for `Vec<&dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r Int) -> Int>`

struct Int{
i : i32
}

```
fn main() {

    let adder = move |x : &Int| Int{ i: x.i + 1}; 
    let v_adder=vec![adder];
    let i_adder=v_adder.iter();
    let v = Vec::from_iter(i_adder);
    let p= v[0](&Int{i:1}).i;
    println!("{}",p)

}
```

But this code works fine. I use from_iter. It means that the trait FromIter is implemented.

---

updated after the kmdreko comment

I´ve change the first main function in order to replace
&dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r Int) -> Int by impl Fn(&Int) -> Int>

```
let adder = move |x : &Int| Int{ i: x.i + 1}; 
let v_adder=vec![adder];
let i_adder=v_adder.iter();
let nv_adder=i_adder.collect::<Vec<impl Fn(&Int) -> Int>>();
```

> error[E0562]: `impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return types, not in path

Comment: `&[closure@...]` != `&dyn Fn(...)`. The same goes for any `&T` != `&dyn Trait`. The latter example works because you make a `Vec<&[closure@...]>` and not a `Vec<&dyn Fn(...)>` like the former example attempts. You need to *coerce* the `&T` into a `&dyn Trait`

Comment: @kmdreko thanks for your comment. I've tried to replace by the type proprosed when I use vec::fromIterator (see update).  It doesn't work either. what I have done, is it what you mean or do you mean something else?

Comment: Why doesn't [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73497899) from your previous question resolve the problem entirely? Why haven't you applied the suggested approach of mapping the elements of the iterator into trait objects?

Comment: Some relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818082/vector-of-objects-belonging-to-a-trait https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957103/how-do-i-create-a-heterogeneous-collection-of-objects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156009/how-to-iterate-over-a-collection-of-structs-as-an-iterator-of-trait-object-refer Please see which one helps you the most.

Comment: @Pierre-olivierGendraud I've written an answer, but I'm still not sure what your actual *goal* is, if you want a `Vec<&dyn Fn(...)>` type because of the dynamicism or simply want something nameable then my answer is what you want. But if you want to collect into a `Vec` without naming the type (as one can't with closures) then just do `.collect::<Vec<_>>()`.

Comment: There is a bigger problem behind all this, it's that, in general, you can't really build vectors of closures *as is*, because all closures have different types. See [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=39ce4b6621d9b392bdb2c7d75adc869b).

Comment: Agreed, @Pierre-olivierGendraud you usually want `Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&Int) -> Int>>` from the start like the answer in your last question partially demonstrates. And shown in other answers that E_net4 has linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `&T` != `&dyn Trait`, even if `T` implements `Trait`. The former can be *coerced* into the latter, often transparently because things like passing function arguments or assigning to a variable are coercion sites. However, they are still different types (even have different sizes) and thus you can't collect into a collection for `&dyn Trait` from an iterator of `&T`s.

To get this to work, you need to introduce a coercion from your iterator, via `.map()`:

```
let nv_adder = v_adder.iter().map(|f| f as &dyn Fn(&Int) -> Int).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e21308f14cdbe7b3f39711cd5d6675b7).